# How to convert datetime string to datetime value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Let's say cells `A1` and `A2` have these values:

> 13 Jan, 02:21 am
>
> 12 Jan, 10:15 pm

And many more values like those below in that column.

What formula could I use so that the `B` column would look like this?

2020-01-12 22:15

I'm confused about `DATE()`, `DATEVALUE()`, `TIMEVALUE()`, etc.

In PHP it is so much easier: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could find no magic function in google sheet.
However, you may use the following.

Before applying this function, you need to add year value like

```
change
"13 Jan, 02:21 am" // google will parse this as current year date as of 2021
to 
"13 Jan 2020, 02:21 am"
```

then

```
=index(split(A1,","),1)+index(split(A1,","),2) 
// split function will trigger automatic type match for each value
```

The above function is equivalent with

```
=datevalue("13 Jan 2020") + timevalue("02:21 am")
```

As cell value will be 43843.09792 as number, you need to change cell value format as DATETIME.

Google Sheet Example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nvvKiLyzZNdekx5-hDpDqzJ6T401G-mASqiKCZbUiQk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This feels hacky but suffices in the short run for my purposes:

`=date("2020","01", left(A1,2))+TIMEVALUE(right(A1,8))`

(And then Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format > "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm".)

But hardcoding the year and month feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137914#153322):

> ```
> change  
> "13 Jan, 02:21 am" // google will parse this as current year date as of 2021
> to  
> "13 Jan 2020, 02:21 am"
> ```

```
=sum(split(A1,","))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these simple formulas *(depending on your desired results).*
Remember to always format the results as `Date time` from the menu.

1. `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,",","")+0`
2. `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,",","2003")+0`
3. `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,",",""&$A$4)+0`

[image]

The 1st formula will always give the **current year**
The 2nd formula the **hard-coded year**
The 3rd one whatever **year is in cell `A4`**

To produce **your "exact" format** use a `Custom date and time`

[image]

**Further reading:**

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`Custom date and time`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Ccustom-date-formatting)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).